# JWT Authorization policy to Ignore expiration (Lifetime)

Tags: .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-authentication

I am working with JWT authentication in Asp.net core 3.0. The application is already setup to use JWT authentication and it is working fine. What I am looking for is to have an endpoint to be able to accessed even the auth token is expired (but all the other checks must be validated). I read about the policies and authentication schemes and played with those but it didn't help. How this can be made possible?  Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

That defeats the whole purpose of the system; why would you want that?

You could technically just increase the lifetime of the token, an example with `IdentityServer4`:

```cs
int tokenLifetime = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(30).TotalSeconds;

services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddInMemoryClients(new[] {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("some_secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "your-scope" },

                AccessTokenLifetime = tokenLifetime
            }
        });
```

Another way is to use `refresh tokens` to renew your `access token`.

Comment: @UsmanIftakhar Well, you could try and look at doing custom token validation using [ICustomTokenRequestValidator](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/custom_token_request_validation.html) that's the only other way I can think of to bypass certain checks.

Then again I'm not sure if you are using IdentityServer to perform token validation?